# Crossbrowser adding/removing MediaElementJS videos

Tags: jquery, firefox, mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElementJS
http://mediaelementjs.com/
so I can have streaming mp4 video on browsers such as IE6+, etc.

I want it so that the video is initially not visible and then it popups up and can be hidden and then possibly come back, replaying from the start.

Possible approaches include initially hiding the video then showing it, then hiding it again...

or dynamically creating the video object then deleting it, then creating a new video object...

One version:
http://vc4hp.net/vidtest/test5.php

iPad: ok, IE9: ok, Chrome: ok

Firefox: "Show" must be pressed twice and there is no sound. http://vc4hp.net/vidtest/test5f.php Has the video initially shown instead of hidden (and autoplay is disabled). If you play the video straight away (you need to press "Show") the sound works. If you hide then show then play it, the sound doesn't work.

IE6-IE8: Need to press "Show" twice... if the delay is too short, either no video is played or there is a blank screen with sound. If the delay is enough the video plays normally. (I haven't been able to make it show the graphics of the video while at the same time only requiring one press of "Show")

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#videocontainer').hide();
    $("#show").click(function () { 
        $('#videocontainer').show('slow');
        if (nativeMP4) {
            $('#player1').attr('src','comm5intro.mp4');
        }
        else {
            if (my_media.length > 0) {
                my_media[0].setSrc('comm5intro.mp4');
                my_media[0].play();
            }
        }        
    });    
    $("#hide").click(function () { 
        $('#videocontainer').hide('slow');
        if (nativeMP4) {
            $('video')[0].pause();
        }
        else {
            if (my_media.length > 0) {
                my_media[0].pause();
            }
        }        
    });        
});
```

Due to the no sound in firefox problem, I've tried a different method - where video objects are created and destroyed:

http://vc4hp.net/vidtest/test11.php

iPad: ok ("Show" makes video appear [doesn't autoplay of course], "Hide" makes video disappear, etc)

IE9: First press of "Show" and "Hide" works. Second press of "Show" plays two videos at once and these don't get deleted when you press "Hide"

Firefox: "Show" makes a video appear, "Hide" doesn't do anything.

Chrome: "Show" usually results in an echo - two videos are probably playing even though the detection of native MP4 support is meant to prevent a second version of it playing. "Hide" stops the echo meaning that the other video is still playing.

IE6-IE8: Like Firefox, "Show" makes another video appear and start playing. "Hide" does nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function () { 
        $('#videocontainer').append('<video id="player1" width="640" height="460" src="comm5intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls="controls" autoplay="true"></video>');
        var v = document.createElement('video'); 
        if (v.canPlayType && v.canPlayType('video/mp4').replace(/no/, '')) { 
            // native MP4 support
            alert('Native MP4 Support');
        } 
        else {
            $('#videocontainer video').mediaelementplayer({features: ['playpause','progress','volume']});
        }
    });    
    $("#hide").click(function () { 
        $('#videocontainer video').remove();
    });    
});
```

I'd like one or both of these methods to work properly in as many of those browsers as possible.

Here is a version that plays the video properly in all the browsers I checked...

http://vc4hp.net/vidtest/test.html

Though the buttons don't seem to work in IE7 and IE8.

Here is a zip of the main files.... http://vc4hp.net/vidtest/mediaelementjs.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works on all of the browsers I've tested and it is very simple:

http://vc4hp.net/vidtest/iframe1.html

Basically it uses an iframe and it is able to be shown and hidden using jquery animations.